Ошибка при изменении отображаемого имени
Подскажите, как изменить своё отображаемое имя здесь на stackoverflow? Поддержка совсем не почему-то не отвечает!
При попытки изменения пишет:

"Ой! При обновлении вашего профиля произошла ошибка".



Так написано же, что имя уже занято. Поменяйте на то имя, которое еще не занято.

Ну и автоимена типа user с номером возможно зарезервированы. Пробуйте имя в другом формате указать.

Какое я бы имя не ввел всегда так пишет!

И какое имя вводите?

До этого имя не меняли? Есть какой-то минимальный срок между изменениями имени, насколько я помню (хотя тогда должно прямо явно про это в ошибке писать)

Я ввожу Eugene260724 сейчас, год назад я кажется менял имя 1 раз всего.

Так я не только имя не могу сменить но и аватар и допустим сайт добавить тоже не могу.

Возможно это связано с тем, что заблокирована возможность задавать вопросы. Из-за большого кол-ва низкокачественных вопросов.

Нет, это было и до этого.

Что будет если оставить поле имени пустым? Имена вида user<номер> вполне могут быть зарезервированы, как уже писали выше. Так как такие имена используются именно в случаях, если имя не указано явно (оставлено пустое поле).

Как я вижу, всё получилось. В чём же была проблема?

Нет, не получилось, мои аккаунты объединили почему-то хотя е-майл у них был разный и они были для разных целей.
